# Numeric Integration

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Consider the following question :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPDmH.png)

Can someone please explain why it's suitable to use here all of the numeric integration techniques?
Also here :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yldEY.png)

Why the trapezoidal rule is the correct answer?

Comment: How do you see a quadratic function there?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry about that. Please see again the question.  There is no quadratic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrand is a linear function. All three rules are exact on linear functions, Simpson's rule even on quadratic functions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the rectangular rule approximates the function as a constant, so how it will be exact on a linear function? Also, for Simpson's rule, it estimates the function as a quadratic one so how it will be exact on a linear function?  Kindly see again the question I have added one more question.

Comment: Let us consider a linear function $f(x)=ax+b$ on interval $[A,B]$. You know that the trapezoidal rule gives you the correct answer $\int_A^B f(x)\,\text{d}x=\frac{f(A)+f(B)}{2}(B-A)=\left[b+a\frac{A+B}{2}\right](B-A)$. Now: 1) you can check, that the rectangular rule gives you exactly the same: $\int_A^B f(x)\,\text{d}x=f\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)(B-A)=\left[b+a\frac{A+B}{2}\right](B-A)$. 2) Simpson's rule is exact on quadratic functions, i.e. on functions of the form $ax^2+bx+c$, which have linear functions as a special case ($a=0$).